# customization of grid layout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I need to display tiles like in the below picture:
[image]

Can I customize the GridLayout somehow to add this tiles programatically?
In my case the 3 and 4 tiles are one below another.
Also I make this with relative layout but I have to much conditions and the code is to hard to maintain.

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Comment: https://github.com/AnkitDroidGit/DynamikGridView-Android this can help you. Please try.

Comment: I will try and I will send you a feedback

Answer (score 0):

[image: gridLayout]

```
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(5);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(2);

    rootView.addView(gridLayout);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(0,1),
            GridLayout.spec(0,2));

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(" button 1");
    button.setWidth(400);
    button.setHeight(200);
    gridLayout.addView(button, gridParams);

    gridParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(1),
            GridLayout.spec(0,1));
    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    button1.setText(" button 2");
    button1.setWidth(200);
    button1.setHeight(200);
    gridLayout.addView(button1, gridParams);

    gridParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(1),
            GridLayout.spec(1,2));

    Button button2 = new Button(this);
    button2.setText(" button 3");
    button2.setWidth(400);
    button2.setHeight(200);
    gridLayout.addView(button2, gridParams);

    gridParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(0,1),
            GridLayout.spec(2,2));

    Button button3 = new Button(this);
    button3.setText(" button 4");
    button3.setWidth(400);
    button3.setHeight(200);
    gridLayout.addView(button3, gridParams);

    gridParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(0,2),
            GridLayout.spec(4,1));

    Button button5 = new Button(this);
    button5.setText(" button 5");
    button5.setWidth(200);
    button5.setHeight(400);
    gridLayout.addView(button5, gridParams);
```